# JAVA. Побитовый сдвиг работает не так, как ожидается

Tags: java

В комментариях - значение **b** в debug:

```
byte b = 80;   // 1010_0000 
b >>>= 7;      // b = 0
```

**b** после сдвига стало **0000_0000**, хотя сдвиг беззнаковый и должно было быть **0000_0001**.

Что не так и как тогда получить "знаковый" бит?

Answer (score 3):

У Вас ошибка в коде. Двоичное число `1010_0000` в десятичном виде будет `160`. А `80` в десятичном, в двоичном будет `0101_0000`. `0101_0000` при беззнаковом сдвиге на семь разрядов влево, действительно даст `0`